# How to upload files in grape swagger rails? (Error: The requested format &#39;txt&#39; is not supported)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, file-upload, swagger, swagger-ui

I need to implement file uploading using Grape UI. We have these gems:

```
gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-entity'
gem 'grape-papertrail'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-entity'
```

In my **attachments_api.rb**:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module V1
  class AttachmentsAPI < ApplicationAPI
    content_type :pdf, 'multipart/form-data'

    resource :attachments do
      desc 'Upload attchment file'
      params do
        requires :file, type: File, documentation: { param_type: 'formData', data_type: 'file' }
      end
      post do
        byebug
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run it in UI (https://editor.swagger.io/), I got same error every time (doesn't matter txt file I try to attach, png or pdf):

```
The requested format &#39;txt&#39; is not supported.
```

More strange looks generated json_doc:

```
paths:
  /attachments:
    post:
      description: Upload attchment file
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file
          type: file
          required: true
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Upload attchment file
      tags:
        - attachments
      operationId: postAttachments
```

I don't understand why we see there

```
consumes:
  - application/json
```

How can I fix this error and make proper file uploading? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `consumes` must be `multipart/form-data`. Check if grape-swagger has an annotation to override the `consumes` value.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
desc 'Upload attachment file', consumes: ['multipart/form-data']
```